# Function not defined in Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have the code below but when I click the button it can't find the required function. I'm not great with scopes so I assume it's something to do with that.

Prior to this I had it set as `var name = function` and it worked until I needed to use the GM_setValue (not defined yet although will be later).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Futbin Extractor
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.futbin.com/players
// @grant        GM_getValue, GM_setValue
// ==/UserScript==

/* global $ */

(function() {
    'use strict';

//defining all the variables


    function extract (e) {
//all the stuff in this function
    }


    function startExtractor () {
        console.log('Starting Extractor');
        extractorRunning = true;

        $('.player_tr_1').each(function () {
            extract(this);
        });

        $('.player_tr_2').each(function () {
            extract(this);
        });
    };

    function siteSetup () {
        var newBox = '<div id="fiddleBar"><button "startButton" onClick="startExtractor();">Test</button></div>';
        $(newBox).insertBefore('#repTb');
    }



    if (!$('#fiddleBar')) {
        siteSetup;
    } else {
        console.log('Repeating Site Setup');
        setTimeout(siteSetup,100);
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of issues to address here. Firstly, you can join the two `.player_tr_1` and `.player_tr_2` selectors in a single jQuery object to loop through together. In addition `if (!$('#fiddleBar'))` will never hit because a jQuery object always coerces to true. Use the `length` property if you want to know if the element exists in the DOM.

With regard to your problem, inline event attributes, such as `onclick`, require the function to be declared in global scope. It's part of the reason they are bad practice and should be avoided. Instead use a delegated event handler, like this:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  
  function extract(e) {
    // all the stuff in this function
  }

  function startExtractor() {
    console.log('Starting Extractor');
    extractorRunning = true;

    $('.player_tr_1, .player_tr_2').each(function() {
      extract(this);
    });
  };
  
  $(document).on('click', '.startButton', function() {
    startExtractor();
  }); 

  function siteSetup() {
    var newBox = '<div id="fiddleBar"><button class="startButton">Test</button></div>';
    $(newBox).insertBefore('#repTb');
  }

  if (!$('#fiddleBar').length) {
    siteSetup();
  } else {
    console.log('Repeating Site Setup');
    setTimeout(siteSetup, 100);
  }
})();
```